# Python please tell me if my maths answer is right

Tags: python

I wish to add a feature which tells the user when he/she has answered correctly to the random maths questions that are given.

```
import random

def answers():
    correct_answer_P_ = ((str(difficulty_one + difficulty_one))) #P = PLUS, ADDITION +  

    correct_answer_M_ = ((str(difficulty_one * difficulty_one))) #M = MULTIPLY *

    correct_answer_T_ = ((str(difficulty_one - difficulty_one))) #T = TAKE AWAY, MINUS -

def random_symbols():
    symbols = random.choice (["+","-","*"])
    return symbols

def difficulty_one():
    dif_one = random.randrange (1,10,1)
    return dif_one

def questions():
    question = (str(difficulty_one())) + random_symbols() + (str(difficulty_one())) + " = "
    return question


start = input("press start to begin!: ")


if (start == "start"):
    print ("here's ten questions, good luck!")
    for questions_num in range(1,11):
        print ("Question ",questions_num)
        input(questions())
        if (random_symbols == "+"):
            if (dif_one == correct_answer_P_):
                            print("correct!")

        elif(random_symbols == "-"):
            if (dif_one == correct_answer_T_):
                            print("correct!")

        elif(random_symbols == "*"):
            if (dif_one == correct_answer_M_):
                            print("correct!")
        else:
            print("incorrect!")
```

I tried this from getting some advice from a friend who said that i needed to create variables for each symbol that would be randomly inserted; the variables should compare the users answer and say its correct but it skips all the if statements and goes straight to saying its incorrect.

Any suggestions? Don't be harsh if I'm doing something dumb because I've just started python at the moment.

Quick note the part in this code has been cut out of my original to make it simple for people to see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Among other things, you're comparing `random_symbols` (the *function itself*) to various strings (`"+"`, etc.), which is always false. However, the real issue is that your whole setup is flawed: those functions will return different values each time they're called. What you really need to do is call them once (per loop), store the results someplace, and then use those in your comparisons and so on.

Comment: Maybe you should head over to codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RPGillespie This is off-topic for codereview, as it's not working code. CR.SE questions are about cleaning up code that produces the right output, not fixing code that produces the wrong output (that's SO's job!!)

Comment: Why do you ask Python?

Comment: for OP: please take the time to make your code an [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, there's bits of code that can likely be trimmed (so it's not minimal), it's missing bits of code (what's `start`?) so it's not complete, and it doesn't run (literally pasting that code and running it doesn't execute anything!) so it's not verifiable!

Answer (score 0):

There's a way easier way of implementing this. Try this instead:

```
import operator

questions = [(1,2), (4,2), (8,1), (10,100)] # operands for your questions
operators = {"+" : operator.add,
             "-" : operator.sub,
             "*" : operator.mul}
# a dictionary containing each operator's symbol and the resulting function
# (operator.add(x,y) is equivalent to x+y)

for num, operands in enumerate(questions,start=1):
    # iterate through each set of operands, enumerating starting at 1 
    operator = random.choice(operators)
    # return a random symbol from operators
    answer = operators[operator](*operands)
    # operators[operator] is the function, which we then call with the operands
    q_text = "{} {} {} = ?".format(str(operands[0]), operator, str(operands[1]))
    print("Question {}".format(str(num)))
    print(q_text)
    user_answer = input(">>")
    if float(user_answer) == answer:
        # correct!
    else:
        # fail!
```

Comment: thanks for the people who commented. im sorry if my question wasn't structured well, i have recently read through (http://codereview.stackexchange.com), and in future will try to keep my question to the criteria the site has set . sorry if i caused any frustration and have disrespected the community in any way. again thanks for the suggestions and i will focus on finishing my work. Happy holidays